# Is it permitted to pick your nose on Shabbos?

Tags: halacha

Is it permitted to pick your nose on Shabbos?

Possible problems: Tochein (see Yerushalmi's comment on Zoreh with spit), Gozez, Muktzah

Comment: Is it permitted to pick it during the week? Baal Teshakzu?

Comment: http://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/22831/can-you-pick-your-nose

Comment: @GershonGold dupe?

Comment: @YeZ No, i think, because this one has a specific Shabbat aspect to it.

Comment: @YEZ: Answer there discusses Shabbos, however does not have source

Comment: @GershonGold See [Sam's answer](http://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/32023).

Comment: RWC, Welcome to Mi Yodeya! Thanks very much for the interesting question, which is related to the one Gershon linked to above. Please consider [registering](http://judaism.stackexchange.com/users/login) your account, which will [give you access](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/44557/why-should-i-register-my-account) to more of the site's features. We hope to see more contributions from you on this site!

Comment: That question doesn't ask about shabbos. The fact that the answer addresses it doesn't make the question a dupe

Comment: @Daniel from the question there: " Would there be a difference in halakah if it were the sabbath?"