# Is it permitted to eat boogers?

Tags: halacha, kashrut-kosher, derech-eretz-manners

I apologize for the question. but is it permitted to eat ones boogers?
possibility of blood? is it Baal Teshakzu? totally permitted similar to nail biting?
and would it be forbidden on shabbos?

Comment: http://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/22831/can-you-pick-your-nose

Answer (score 3):

[Alex](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/users/37/alex) wrote this as an answer to [this question](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/16429/9643):

> Based on the verse ([Lev. 11:43](http://www.mechon-mamre.org/p/pt/pt0311.htm#43)), אל תשקצו את נפשותיכם - "do not make yourselves detestable," there is indeed a halachah that one may not eat things that are disgusting to the average person. Shulchan Aruch ([Yoreh De'ah 116:6](http://www.hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=9146&st=&pgnum=20)) puts it as follows:
>
> > אסור לאכול מאכלים ומשקים שנפשו של אדם קצה בהם, כגון משקים ואוכלים שנתערבו בהם קיא או צואה או ליחה סרוחה וכיוצא בהם... שכל אלו בכלל אל תשקצו את נפשותיכם
> >
> > It is forbidden to eat foods and drinks that are repellent to a [normal] person, such as drinks or foods into which vomit, excreta, pus or the like have been mixed... for all of these are included in the [prohibition], "Do not make yourselves detestable."

(*Credit: [Double AA](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/users/759/double-aa)*)